How to make Fairphone built-in file manager remember the "move to" location?
Is there any way to make the built-in/factory-installed file manager on a Fairphone 3 remember the last target location I chose when I marked one or multiple files with a longer finger press and chose "move to"?
I guess it's called "move to", my Android is not in English.
I'm using Android 13.

Just in case, are you open to an alternative/3rd-party file manager app?

I guess I'd accept a good tip for another file manager as answer :)
